# Need a formula to get total LUN size using lunSizeLow and lunSizeHigh SNMP objects

Tags: binary, snmp, endianness, mib

I have 2 `SNMP` Objects/OIDs. Below are the details:

**`Object1`:**

```
Name: lunSizeLow

OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.43906.1.4.3.2.3.1.9

Description: `LUN` size in bytes - low order bytes
```

**`Object2`:**

```
Name: lunSizeHigh

OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.43906.1.4.3.2.3.1.10

Description: `LUN` size in bytes - high order bytes
```

**My requirement**:

I want to monitor `LUN` size through some script. But i didn't found any `SNMP` object, which can give total `LUN` size directly. I found 2 separate objects (`lunSizeLow` and `lunSizeHigh`) to get `LUN` total size, so i need a formula to get total `LUN` size using these 2 low order and high order `SNMP` objects (`lunSizeLow` and `lunSizeHigh`).

I gone through many articles over internet and i found couple of formulas in [community.hpe.com](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Array-Setup-and-Networking/Interpreting-SNMP-Parameters-For-High-and-Low-Order-Bytes/td-p/6983774).

But I'm not sure which one is correct.

**Formula 1:**

Max unsigned number that can be stored in `32bits` counter is `4294967295`.

Total size would be: `LOW_ORDER_BYTES + HIGH_ORDER_BYTES * 4294967296`

**Formula 2:**

Total size in GB is `LOW_ORDER_BYTES / 1073741824 + HIGH_ORDER_BYTES * 4`

Could any one help me to get correct formula.

Comment: Re-tagged the question since it's not really SNMP specific.

Comment: As usual on StackOverflow, please specify what you have tried, and what your results were. You list two alternatives, does either of them work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Most languages will have the bit-shift operator, allowin you to do something similar to the below (pseudo-Java):

```
long myBigInteger = lunSizeHigh
myBigInteger << 32 # Shifts the high bits 32 positions to the left, into the high half of the long
myBigInteger = myBigInteger + lunSizeLow
```

This has two advantages over multiplying:

1. Bit shifting is often faster than multiplication, even though most compilers would optimize that particular multiplication into a bit shift anyway.
2. It is easier to read the code and understand why this would provide the correct answer, given the description from the MIB. Magic numbers should be avoided where possible.

That aside, putting some numbers into the Windows Calculator (using Programmer Mode) and trying formula 1, we can see that it works.

Now, you don't specify what language or environment you're working in, and in some languages you won't have any number type that supports the size of numbers you want to manipulate. (Same reason that this number had to be split into two counters to begin with - it's larger than the largest number representation available on some (primitive) platforms.) If you want to do it using multiplication, you'll have to make sure your implementation language can do better.